# EXT-fs error that won't let up

Tags: boot, mount, 15.10, ext4, fsck

I have a Xubuntu 15.10 dual boot with Windows. This started yesterday, I was trying to create a Xubuntu 15.10 USB live disk so I could help a friend. I had errors with it but now my system will dismount, then mount read-only. I had to fix it TWICE with `fsck` in the `initramfs` shell. It did it again. here is the latest log on the error:

```
[  337.064235] EXT4-fs error (device sda7): ext4_ext_check_inode:496: inode #24798: comm duplicity: pblk 0 bad header/extent: invalid magic - magic 0, entries 0, max 0(0), depth 0(0)
[  337.064404] Aborting journal on device sda7-8.
[  337.064553] EXT4-fs (sda7): Remounting filesystem read-only
[  337.064600] EXT4-fs error (device sda7): ext4_ext_check_inode:496: inode #24798: comm duplicity: pblk 0 bad header/extent: invalid magic - magic 0, entries 0, max 0(0), depth 0(0)
[  337.628356] EXT4-fs error (device sda7): ext4_ext_check_inode:496: inode #24880: comm duplicity: pblk 0 bad header/extent: invalid magic - magic 0, entries 0, max 0(0), depth 0(0)
[  337.628532] EXT4-fs error (device sda7): ext4_ext_check_inode:496: inode #24880: comm duplicity: pblk 0 bad header/extent: invalid magic - magic 0, entries 0, max 0(0), depth 0(0)
[  337.630315] EXT4-fs error (device sda7): ext4_ext_check_inode:496: inode #754: comm duplicity: pblk 0 bad header/extent: invalid magic - magic 0, entries 0, max 0(0), depth 0(0)
[  337.630463] EXT4-fs error (device sda7): ext4_ext_check_inode:496: inode #754: comm duplicity: pblk 0 bad header/extent: invalid magic - magic 0, entries 0, max 0(0), depth 0(0)
```

I really don't want to have to redo this dual boot. Could anyone help please?

I have tried `fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda7`.

Comment: You might want to run the memtest option at the boot menu to see if you have bad ram.  Otherwise it looks like the disk is silently corrupting data.

Comment: Maybe, it is because `duplicity` is an interference.

Comment: I don't think so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicity was interfering with my data. I removed Deja-Dup and `duplicity` from my system.